# Time Stack Chart with years as horizontal axis

Tags: anylogic

I want to add a stacked chart but could not find a way to customize the time-axis.

Currently my x-axis refers to days, however, I search for a way to display years. Since I want a stacked chart that changes over time, I believe I need to use the 'Time Stack Chart' (see screenshot). I would also be happy with simply several stacked bars next to each other (each bar represents one year), but the 'Bar Chart' only supports one bar (I believe).

My model collects data from different sources on the last day of the year and then my chart should display this value for the year, categorized by source. I have tried with different data sets, both where the time is the horizontal value and where it is not.

When I use a dataset where one value is 'Years' (through the getYear() function) this works fine for plots, but not when I want to have a stacked chart (which by default depends on the time).

Is there a solution to this?
Please let me know if you need further information!

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you do the data collection at the end of the year? Why not continuously?

Comment: And in the scale section, if you change `model time units` to `years`, it doesn't help?

Comment: I would also be ok with continuously, but the problem I think remains

Comment: Ah right, I changed the model time to years and now it shows values 1-13. 
That solves my problem halfway, is there a way to use model years (eg 2022, 2023...) instead of 1,2,3...?
Thank you very much!

Comment: In the data update part, if you select `Use calendar dates`, that helps?

Comment: That makes no difference unfortunately..

Comment: Under the appearance part, time axis format, set to `yyyy`

Comment: cool, writing this answer, please upvote and accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the appearance part, time axis format, set it to `yyyy`. Also in the scale section, you need to change model time units to years.